# ARC with zombies - Why do objects in instance variables not get released when owning object is deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is object not dealloc'ed when using ARC + NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled)

In a project using ARC with zombie objects enabled, if an object holds a strong reference to another object when it is deallocated, that other object does not get released.

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
@interface TestInner : NSObject

@end

@implementation TestInner

- (id)init {
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
    }
    NSLog(@"-[TestInner init]: %p", self);
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"-[TestInner dealloc]: %p", self);
}

@end

@interface TestOuter : NSObject

@end

@implementation TestOuter {
    TestInner * _inner;
}

- (id)init {
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        _inner = [[TestInner alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"-[TestOuter init]: %p", self);
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"-[TestOuter dealloc]: %p", self);

    //  _inner will not release without this if zombies are enabled
    //_inner = nil;
}

@end
```

Allocating and releasing a TestOuter instance yields the following log messages:

```
-[TestInner init]: 0x9d00f00
-[TestOuter init]: 0x9d00f30
-[TestOuter dealloc]: 0x9d00f30
```

The TestInner instance is never deallocated. Turning off zombies will, however, cause the TestInner instance to be deallocated.

One of the benefits of switching to ARC was that we so rarely needed to implement a dealloc method simply to release held object references. It seems that with zombies enabled, which is useful to have to catch all kinds of mistakes during development, that this benefit cannot be realized. I will still need to implement dealloc methods just to set my held references to `nil`.

Am I missing something here, or is this really the expected behavior when mixing ARC with zombies?

Comment: Well, zombie detection wasn't compatible with leak detection in the past. This sounds expected -- the object has to remain around, so it can report that it's a zombie.

Comment: @DavidDunham from what I know, that is not true. The object gets exchanged with a special zombie object, it does not stay.

Comment: It's the same pointer, so for all intents and purposes, it stays. See http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-20-the-inner-life-of-zombies.html

Comment: I think with nszombie enabled, _inner dealloc should have been called. Yes object should not be deallocated because it turns into zombie instead. But weak references should be nilled and dealloc should still be called. Otherwise program will be have differently whether you have zombie or not zombie. Should here, does not mean it really does. Does it? Anyone knows?