# ARC weird behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

With ARC enabled I have a property

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

I Allocate it as

```
  self.arr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I have a custom object ERSearchView, I allocate it and add it to the arr

```
  ERSearchView *SV = [[ERSearchView alloc] initWithDelegate:nil];
  [arr addObject:SV];
```

In my search view I have overridden the `dealloc` method, because it seems that the search view isn't getting released:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  self.delegate = nil;
  NSLog(@"deallocated search view");
}
```

This isn't getting called when I pop my view controller. But if I nil the arr variable in the view controller's `dealloc` I see the log message that the search view has been deleted.

Can anyone explain how is this possible that objects inside `arr` aren't getting released though the view controller is 100% released since I have "did dealloc" message in its `dealloc`?

Comment: i think you are missing the [super dealloc] in your dealloc method. and try to avoid accessors in your init and dealloc method, instead use iVars

Comment: With ARC enabled you can't directly call `dealloc`, even within the scope of sending the message to your superclass.

Comment: You didnt called [super dealloc] in the override of dealloc, but according to me it's not because you released a container that all what he contained is released ...

Comment: My normal approach to figuring out this kind of thing has been to use Instruments to look at the object's retain count history.  I don't know how well that works with ARC.  I suppose I should find out.  :)

Comment: NSMutableArray retains the objects. Who owns your array (ie. self.arr)? And is the array being properly released?

Comment: @JohnSmith, you can't call `dealloc` directly with ARC enabled. See my previous comment.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks, but the issue is that with ARC enabled all the retain-release routine must be done automatically and it doesn't appear to be happening.

Comment: @DavidV Thank you, I know that NSMutableArray retains its objects, but the point is that it should get implicitly released when my view controller's dealloc method gets called. UIViewController subclass owns the `arr`. And no, apparently it isn't getting properly released, that's the reason I created this post :)

Comment: @Eugene -- So, you're saying Instruments doesn't report the effect of the ARC memory management?

Comment: Are you sure that your view controller is being deallocated? iOS does not deallocate views when the user leaves the view, and instead sends -viewWillUnload. Also, is it possible that some other class is retaining your array? It appears to be a public property.

Comment: It's a private property and as I said the view controller is getting released, since I have overridden its dealloc and put in the "did dealloc message" which gets called when I pop the controller.

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm not sure how to debug such behavior with instruments. I mean I know how to use Leaks, but that's about it. Anyways, this seems like an easy issue that must not require additional debugging with heavy artillery of instruments.

Comment: @Eugene, Instruments is a good tool for this problem. You can see which code retains your objects. Also, it might help to have more source code for us on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation collection classes such as `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc. retain (or have a strong reference to, in ARC-speak) the objects they contain. So as long as the array hasn't been deallocated, the objects it refers to, including your view instance, should still be in memory.

It sounds as though you were leaking the array previously by not setting the property to `nil` in the controller's `dealloc` method. When an object declares a property as `strong`, it's responsible for the nilling the reference in its `dealloc` implementation to avoid this kind of leak.

Comment: Really? I mean really you need to nil the strong variables in ARC enabled environment? O_O I thought that was made automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this again, but could you please provide any reference to any document where I could read about this? I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: It helped!! I'm so grateful, thank you so much! You are a life savior, I was going to switch to manual memory management. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is only needed when running with NSZombie enabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857518/arc-with-zombies-why-do-objects-in-instance-variables-not-get-released-when-ow

Comment: @Eugene switching to Manual Memory Management is a really bad idea. Learn the semantics of ARC and it will save you tons of trouble. `strong` implies ownership, and so long as at least one object claims ownership of a child object, that child object stays in memory. You must release ownership on your own (or if it's just an ivar, this gets done for you in all your dealloc methods which are created for you by the compiler… naturally, if you override the compiler, you need to handle this yourself).

Comment: @Eugene Here's Apple's reference document on ARC: [Trasitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=transitioning%20to%20arc%20release%20notes&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2F%23releasenotes%2FObjectiveC%2FRN-TransitioningToARC%2F_index.html&ei=OsDGT5KCMciL0QG1gqStCw&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=bVxVBbseoQSQcTxNOTw2Ww)

Comment: @GBegen I actually was wrong with accepting this answer. Begen you are absolutely correct, this behavior was caused by NSZombieEnabled option turned on. Thank you very much, if you'd add this as an answer I'd accept it.