# Strange ARC issue not releasing ivar in UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is object not dealloc'ed when using ARC + NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled)

I've got a very strange issue I'm seeing at the moment in a project. Put simply I have `ViewA` which owns `ViewB` (`strong` property). `ViewA` creates its `ViewB` in its initialiser. Both objects are subclasses of `UIView`.

I have overridden `dealloc` in both and put a log line and a break point to see if they get hit. It seems that `ViewA`'s `dealloc` is being hit but not `ViewB`'s. However if I put in a `self.viewB = nil` in the `dealloc` of `ViewA` then it *is* hit.

So basically it's something like this:

```
@interface ViewA : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewB *viewB;
@end

@implementation ViewA

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.viewB = [[ViewB alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self addSubview:self.viewB];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    //self.viewB = nil; ///< Toggling this commented/uncommented changes if ViewB's dealloc gets called.
    NSLog(@"ViewA dealloc");
}

@end
```

What I can't understand is why nil-ing `viewB` out makes a difference. If something else is holding onto `viewB` then it should make absolutely no difference if I nil it out or not here. And it shouldn't make a difference to the number of releases that ARC adds in either.

I can't seem to reproduce it in a minimal test case as yet, but I'm working on it. And I can't post the actual code I'm seeing this in unfortunately. I don't see that being an issue though because it's more the point that nil-ing it out shouldn't make a difference that I am confused by.

Can anyone see anything I am overlooking or give advice about where to look for debugging this problem?

**Update:**

I've found the problem. It appears that it's only a problem when `NSZombieEnabled` is set to `YES`. Well that is entirely mad and has to be a bug surely. Zombies should not affect how this works as far as I know. The objects should still go through the `dealloc` method. And what's more, it's just mad that it works if I nil out `viewB` in `ViewA`'s `dealloc`.

Comment: As an off-topic, you can make it `weak` and forget about the issue: `[self addSubview:self.viewB]` retains `viewB` for you, so it wouldn't get released prematurely even if you keep a `weak` reference to it.

Comment: Unless he needs to run on iOS 4.3.

Comment: Precisely. I want it to run on iOS 4.x and also, I **shouldn't have to do that**. I don't see why nil-ing `viewB` in `dealloc` is making a difference. That just seems mad to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that this appears to be a bug in the iOS implementation of zombies. Consider the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassB : NSObject
@end

@implementation ClassB
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ClassB dealloc");
}
@end

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassB *b;
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize b;
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ClassA dealloc");
}
@end

int main() {
    ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    return 0;
}
```

That should output:

```
ClassA dealloc
ClassB dealloc
```

But with `NSZombieEnabled` set to `YES`, it outputs:

```
ClassA dealloc
```

As far as I can tell, this is a bug. It seems to only happen with iOS (both simulator and device) and does not happen when built and run for Mac OS X. I've filed a radar with Apple.

**Edit:** It turns out this has already been answered here - [Why is object not dealloc'ed when using ARC + NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled) . Managed to find it after I found out what the real problem was. It's nothing to do with ARC by the way.

Comment: offtopic: no [super dealloc]; calls?

Comment: @meccan - No, since I'm using ARC.