# Dealloc of UITableView not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios

I have created some UITableViews in storyboard and written custom classes for each of them. I have dragged and dropped the tableview objects into my main view controller to access them. In the UITableView custom classes, I allocate some class level objects in "numberOfSectionsInTableView" delegate method. I want to release all the class level objects allocated in the numberOfSectionsInTableView method in the dealloc method. But the dealloc is not getting called even if I move to some other view controller. Does anyone have any idea why this is not called, or where else I can release these objects. (ARC is turned off)

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219030/dealloc-not-being-called-on-arc-app

Comment: What are "class level objects"? And in what `-dealloc` are you trying to release them?

Comment: I meant to say class level variables. In the UITableView custom class's dealloc im tryiing to release them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find something about `UIViewController` life cycle.
Try to release your objects in `viewDidUnload` method and put breakpoints there.
This pic should be useful for you:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you could do:

1. turn ARC on?
2. Are you sure its not accessed? make an `NSLog(@"ACCESSED");` in your dealloc method
3. use viewDidUnload method to release things
4. directly release them in their methods if they are not needed anymore

Comment: You can turn on ARC and changing the build flags, you can disable ARC for some specific headers if you like.. click on your project -->targets -->build phases --> "Compile Sources" and then double click on a .m file and type in "-fno-objc-arc" this will diable ARC for the specific file ,)