# Swift setting object to nil does not release memory

Tags: objective-c, swift, memory-management

I have an optional property of my class of type viewController

```
var vc : UIViewController()?
```

I later present that view controller as a popover using some custom code.

Upon dismissing the popOver controller I set the variable to nil

```
vc = nil
```

But the object is never release (and dealloc method of the viewcontroller is not called)

This worked in objective c but not in swift for me

Is there anything else I have to do in order to force an object to be released in swift (other than setting it to nil)?

Comment: Setting to nil should be sufficient to release an object. You most likely have a problem in the code using `vc` - possibly some cyclic dependency is introduced somewhere.

Comment: same exact code that i use in obj c and works fine. I'm using a bridging header to call some obj c code in the process so maybe thats where the problem is

Comment: How are u checking to see if the object is released?

Comment: @MendyK dealloc is never called on the viewcontroller, I put an "NSLog" in the dealloc method

Comment: Have you run Analyze: Shift-Command-B

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219030/dealloc-not-being-called-on-arc-app) answer?

Comment: I'm noticing the same issue, checked the code for retain cycles

Comment: Yeah I never found an answer to this. Maybe Swift 2 will fix....