# Automatic Reference Counting not working

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is object not dealloc'ed when using ARC + NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled)

I must be doing something wrong here. Compiler is set to Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 and Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting is set to YES. I also have 3rd Party Software included that requires ARC to be active.

So my basic problem is that my properties don't get released. I have the following header:

```
@interface ArchiveController : UIViewController <CloseSubviewDelegate> {
  NSArray *journals;
  NSMutableArray *archiveViews;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *journals;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *archiveViews;

....

@end
```

I synthesized those and initialize the archiveViews array like this:

```
self.archiveViews = [NSMutableArray array];
```

later I add objects to it, everything works fine; same for the journals array.

I added a dealloc method to check that the ArchiveController gets released:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   DLog(@"dealloc archive controller");
}
```

which works, but the arrays are never released; Why? If I change the dealloc method to this:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  DLog(@"dealloc archive controller");
  self.archiveViews = nil;
}
```

everything works fine, but thats not the way it should be, right? I'm a 100 % certain that the array and its objects aren't referenced anywhere else.

And isn't the Preprocessor supposed to handle the insertion of all the retains/releases/deallocs? when I let Xcode generate preprocessed output, nothing seems changed!

Comment: How do you know array isn't released?

Comment: It's possible to turn ARC off on a file-by-file basis, by adding per-file compilation flags in the build phase area. Presumably that's not the case here, but it may be worth double-checking. The flag that would turn this off is `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: because the objects inside the array are never released. Thx Kevin for noticing, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a circular dependency.

Instruments can help you locate them at times.

Comment: If there was a retain cycle here, then his `-dealloc` wouldn't be called at all, which means the `self.archiveViews = nil;` would never be run.